# Redirect only certain nonexistent directories

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect

I have this code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/? event.php?e=$1 [L]
```

I was hoping to get it automated, since new links could be added at any time. If it is possible, how could I make it work with only certain directories/links (I have a Javascript array with all the values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of directories or links you want to redirect to `event.php` you can do something like:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 ^directory1 [OR]
RewriteCond $1 ^file1.php [OR]
RewriteCond $1 ^directory2/file2.php [OR]
RewriteCond $1 ^last/file.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ event.php?e=$1 [L]
```